# Strange vim-latex behaviour

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I have a problem when reinstalling vim-latex (possibly installing a newer version).
Here is the code I typed

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\pi$

$2^5$

\textbf{abc}

$2^{\pi}$
\end{document}
```

`$\pi$` became π, `$2^5$` became 2<sup>5</sup>, `\textbf{abc}` became **abc** and so on.

Screenshot:

[image: Here's a screenshot of it]

How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the vim variable conceallevel is being set to 2.

How to fix this depends on your specific vim setup, if you run `:verbose set conceallevel?` in vim, then you will see where conceallevel is being set. If it's in your .vimrc then delete that line. If it's in a plugin (such as indentLine, which sets conceallevel to 2) then you can read through the plugins documentation and disable that plugin (in the case of indentLine you can either use `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex IndentLinesDisable` or `let g:indentLine_noConcealCursor=2` which only causes the text to be expanded when your cursor is on that line.